# Go App Engine debugging

Tags: google-app-engine, debugging, go

I'm using dev_appserver.py to run my Go App locally on my Ubuntu machine. I'm trying to debug the application but can't seem to find the go process to attach a debugger to. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking.. Simply run `ps aux | grep _app_go` to get your pid, then attach from there.

Comment: I have seen that proposed solution, but running dev_appserver.py doesn't create a process like that. App engine doc mentions running goapp serve but there is no goapp command with the latest SDK.

Comment: Yeah, the latest "preferred" way is to use the gcloud sdk and run as you are doing. I personally have not updated to this and still use the old packaged SDK simply because many of these types of issues arise. `goapp` is still my friend....

Answer (score 0):

The process you are looking for when running the go-appengine-sdk using the google-cloud-sdk is `_go_app`. Simply modifying my app to start with a NoOp infinite for loop was enough to send it to the top of the CPU usage list so I could find it.

[image]

So on Ubuntu, a simple `ps aux | grep _go_app` should list the PID.

P.S. This was done on a Mac, so it's possible (however unlikely) that it could be different. But doing your own NoOp for loop to find it would work anyway.